# Shopify checkout UI Extension Error"Window not defined". While trying to import an external module

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, remix, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

We are working on extending our app functionality into the new Shopify checkout ui extension and I'm trying to import a an external module into my `scr/Checkout.tsx` file and when i run my code it  throws the error below.

```
I'm not sure how i could import the module and have it run since its the main dependency for the app syntax to run!
: 
ReferenceError: window is not defined at Object.<anonymous> (https://assets.prd.shoprunner.io/@shoprunner/shopping@1/es6/index.js:1:10825) at Object.<anonymous> (https://assets.prd.shoprunner.io/@shoprunner/shopping@1/es6/index.js:1:10858) at l (https://assets.prd.shoprunner.io/@shoprunner/shopping@1/es6/index.js:1:9983) at Module.<anonymous> (https://assets.prd.shoprunner.io/@shoprunner/shopping@1/es6/index.js:1:32749) at l (https://assets.prd.shoprunner.io/@shoprunner/shopping@1/es6/index.js:1:9983) at https://assets.prd.shoprunner.io/@shoprunner/shopping@1/es6/index.js:1:10771 at https://assets.prd.shoprunner.io/@shoprunner/shopping@1/es6/index.js:1:10781 at https://assets.prd.shoprunner.io/@shoprunner/shopping@1/es6/index.js:1:9848 at https://assets.prd.shoprunner.io/@shoprunner/shopping@1/es6/index.js:1:9853 at https://assets.prd.shoprunner.io/@shoprunner/shopping@1/es6/index.js:127:7213
message
: 
"window is not defined"
stack
```

I already set my ``[extensions.capabilities]`network_access = true`in the `shopify.ui.extension.toml`. Also i thought it was because the window object was loading after my code had run so i created a delay function but still it did not help at all.

```
 const loadModule = async () => {
        const module = import('the url link goes here ');
        return module;
    };
```

Comment: did you find any solution to this? I am running into the same problem. Have to load a module and get it to run.

Answer (score 0):

I had run into the same problem. Since its a very new API, I dont suppose they will add support for that anytime soon.

The API's available now is listed here https://shopify.dev/docs/api/checkout-ui-extensions/unstable/targets/block/purchase-thank-you-block-render#standardapi

You can use the old approach of calling shopify API inject script into the page. Then from that script load all the things you need under the `View` element which can be given an `id`